# USB - PC memory leak in HID class.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I devloped  system using PIC18F26J50. I wrote a PC program using the Microchip “Generic HID - HID DLL  Library” for communication  . I am  continuously  reading  the  byte data using  USBREADREPORT mehods. The program works for ~2 hours and then the performance degrades. I was looking with Windows Task Manager and observed that the Handle count increased  continuously   and  increases in time. This indicates a memory leak. I thought that I have a mistake in my program but I insolated the problem and fond the memory leak in the HID class.dll.
Is there  any solution   that solved this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help

```
       while (true)
          {
            lock (this)
                {
                 unsafe
                  {

                        if ((PerformUsBdataRead()) && (InputPacketBuffer[0] != Nodata))
                        {
                            //handle stylus events same as mouse events
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
 //perform USB Read
  private static bool PerformUsBdataRead()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(65);

            InputPacketBuffer[0] = 0;
            byte* inputPacketBufferPointer = (byte*)unmanagedPointer.ToPointer();

                if (HIDClass.MCHPHIDClass.USBHIDReadReport(inputPacketBufferPointer))
                {
                    unmanagedPointer = (IntPtr)inputPacketBufferPointer;
                    Marshal.Copy(unmanagedPointer, InputPacketBuffer, 0, 65);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
                    return true;
                }                  
                else                 
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
                    return false;
                }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code, are you disposing all unmanaged resources?

Comment: Yes, I have released unmanaged resources while getting the USB data.Below is the code snippet where I check the USB connection in while loop:

Comment: I checked USB connection in WM_DEVICECHANGE. After that When I read data without checking the connection, I didn't get any data. Why it requires to check the connection repeatedly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any alternative or quick fixes for HID.dll? please reply if have any suggestion                                                       Thanks,

Comment: I'm having somewhat of a similar issue.  Have you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Recently micro chip releases new HID.dll. you get it from the micro chip.in which memory leak issue has been resolved.